# helm pass all values files from specific folder

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a folder containing multiple values.yaml files and I would like to pass all the yaml files in that folder as an argument to helm install.

It is possible to use like `helm install example . -f values/values1.yaml -f values/values2.yaml`

But there are more than 10 files in values folder Is it possible to simply pass a folder as an argument

I already tried `helm install example . -f values/*` And this does not work.

Comment: Provided answer is correct from my perspective. You can check github issues with similar feature requests which are open or closed with no actions: [Feature: Support for multiple values files in helm charts #659](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-kubernetes/issues/659) or [Allow multiple yaml files to be included in a single values.yaml #2776](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2776). There's a [workaround](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2776#issuecomment-320999010), but it may not work.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as `-f` expects a file or URL = `specify values in a YAML file or a URL (can specify multiple)` and helm does not know a command to use a directory.

Maybe you should reduce your values.yaml files to have a base value file and then one environment specific values file:

```
helm install example . -f values.yaml -f env/values_dev.yaml
```